# Is there a text file that translates app names like "com.google.android.youtube" to names that people understand like "YouTube"?

Tags: android

I have a text file with app names like "com.android.chrome", "com.whatsapp", and "com.google.android.youtube" and I want to convert them to names like "Chrome", "WhatsApp", and "YouTube".

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PackageManager` to get application name

```
final PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
ApplicationInfo ai;
try {
    ai = pm.getApplicationInfo( "com.google.android.youtube", 0);
} catch (final NameNotFoundException e) {
    ai = null;
}
final String applicationName = (String) (ai != null ? pm.getApplicationLabel(ai) : "(unknown)");
```

You should change `com.google.android.youtube` to your preferred package name